# incorrect time in Android Studio event log

Tags: android, android-studio

My local timezone is `EET` and the current time is `10:38 PM`. When I open the `event log` window in Android Studio, I see that time is `3:38 PM`. Logcat time is true but event log window show wrong time. I can not find any option about timezone in Android Studio. How can I fix this?

My android studio version is `3.2.1`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you already have a virtual or physical device running, your Android Studio logs will print out the time of that device. Meaning, check your connected device current system time, set it to your current E.E.T, and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: thanks but logcat time is same with my pc and phone time. but event log time is wrong. can it be because of java environment ?